# SwiftUI system layout breaks when using custom transition and custom identifier

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui, transition

I have an issue with the SwiftUI system layout on Xcode 12.5.1
On a Text View, I'm using a custom transition(), which is based on custom ViewModifiers. In addition, I'm also using a custom id() that allow me to tell the system that this Text View is not the same, therefore triggering a transition animation.

When using these 2 modifiers on a view, its parent and the content itself doesn't respect the system layout expected behaviour. You can see exactly what happens [in this video](https://youtu.be/sMXDwfiTqe4)

Expected behaviour
[image: Expected behaviour]

Actual behaviour
[image: Actual behaviour]

Here is my sample project code that you can test yourself :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let contentArray: [String] = ["QWEQWE", "ASDASD", "TOTO", "FOO", "BAR"]
    @State private var content: String = "content"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text(self.content)
                    // commenting either the transition modifier, or the id modifier, make the system layout work as expected. The problem comes from using both at the same time
                    .transition(.customTransition)
                    .id(self.content)
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
            Button("action") {
                guard let newValue = self.contentArray.randomElement() else {
                    print("Failed to get a random element from property contentArray")
                    return
                }
                withAnimation {
                    self.content = newValue
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}

extension AnyTransition {
    static var customTransition: AnyTransition {
        // uncomment the following line make the system layout work as expected. The problem comes from AnyTransition.modifier(active:identity:)
//        return AnyTransition.slide.combined(with: .opacity)
        let outAnimation = AnyTransition.modifier(active: CustomTrailingOffset(percent: 1), identity: CustomTrailingOffset(percent: 0)).combined(with: .opacity)
        let inAnimation = AnyTransition.modifier(active: CustomLeadingOffset(percent: 1), identity: CustomLeadingOffset(percent: 0)).combined(with: .opacity)
        return AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: inAnimation, removal: outAnimation)
    }
}

struct CustomLeadingOffset: ViewModifier {
    var percent: CGFloat = 0
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            content.offset(CGSize(width: -geo.size.width*self.percent, height: 0.0))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTrailingOffset: ViewModifier {
    var percent: CGFloat = 0
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            content.offset(CGSize(width: geo.size.width*self.percent, height: 0.0))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.device)
            .previewDevice("iPhone 12")
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 12.5.1

I've found nothing regarding this behaviour during my researches, not on blog posts, not on forums, not on official documentation, that's the reason why I'm posting this question here, in case anyone ever encounter this problem, knows why it occurs, or knows a solution. I've fill a radar (FB9605660) to Apple in parallel but I'm not sure if I'll be informed to their conclusions.

Comment: No bug here - it is an effect of `GeometryReader` in root - use it in background and pass up fetched/calculated offset via view preferences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I wasn't aware of the impact of geometryReader, I wish that was explicitly said in the GeometryReader documentation. Also not familiar with the view preferences yet but I'll take a look.